# Сделать Custom pop up menu

Tags: android

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать вот такое Pop Up меню для смены языка в Android. Интересует создание именно самого View, а не то, как поменять язык в приложении.
Требования в View:

1. в закрытом состоянии необходимо показывать текущий язык
2. в развернутом состоянии выпадает одна секция с невыбранным языком при этом стрелка выбранного переворачивается

Картинки прикладываю.

Всем заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно где именно у вас возникли проблемы. Вопрос выглядит так - "мне нужна вьюха, вот требования, сделайте". Это обычный диалог с вашей разметкой. Делаете макет, который будет соответствовать вашим требованиям. Вот например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/drop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="English"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/drop"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_height="24dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unselected_lang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="Some language"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selected_lang"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

у виджета с `id -> unselected_lang` видимость gone. Дальше подвязываете в активности эту разметку к вашему диалогу. Например так:

```
val dialog = Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(context)).apply {
                setContentView(R.layout.log_out_dialogue)
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.drop).setOnClickListener {
                    
                }
            }



            val window = dialog.window

            window?.attributes =  window!!.attributes.apply { gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM  }

            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel_logout_dialog).setOnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() }

            Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dialog.show()
```

дальше в обработчике нажатий делаете управление видимостью вашего скрытого виджета:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.unselected_lang).visibility = if (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.unselected_lang).visibility == View.GONE) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

ну и дальше уже подвязываете то что вам нужно при перевыборе языка. Но ваши требования заточены под один язык. Для двух и более локализаций я бы советовал использовать список.

P.S. В следующий раз задавайте вопросы более конкретно, с прикладыванием кода.